# JavaScript: Add Method to Array.prototype Object to Exclude Index Values from an Input Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, prototype

I want to write code that adds the doNotInclude method to the Array.prototype object.

The purpose of my code is: does not include the index values from the array passed to `doNotInclude`.

Code below:

```
Array.prototype.doNotInclude = function (arr) {
  //if (!Array.isArray(arr)) arr = [arr];
  return this.filter((val, i) => {
    if (!arr.includes(i)) return val;
  });
};

['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'].doNotInclude([0, 1])
```

My code executes successfully and returns:

```
[ 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six' ]
```

My question is what is the following line of code doing?

```
//if (!Array.isArray(arr)) arr = [arr];
```

In my example, commenting it out does not appear to impact the output, so I'm curious in what situations would I need that line of code?

Comment: For a single index argument like `doNotInclude(1)`

Comment: That filter isn't right ... should return boolean

Comment: One small tip — the callback to `filter()` should return a boolean. So you can just return the result of includes: `return this.filter((val, i) => !arr.includes(i));` As it is now it also filters out `0` and anything else falsy regardless of the index.

Comment: [The pernicious effects of Prototype mutation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/The_performance_hazards_of__%5B%5BPrototype%5D%5D_mutation#Pernicious_effects_of_Prototype_mutation)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's checking to see if your input is an array, and if not, it makes it into a single element array.

This is because the logic of the code requires the input to be an array since it uses `Array.includes()`. This line will never execute if your input is always an array, so it's not technically necessary, but it would allow you to pass

```
1
```

as well as

```
[1]
```

and not get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The code `if (!Array.isArray(arr)) arr = [arr];` is just a safeguard. It converts the argument `arr` into an array, if it's not already one. In other words, that piece of code enables the following behavior:

```
['zero', 'one', 'two'].doNotInclude(0) // Notice that the number is passed
```

Whereas without that safeguard, the above code would simply fail. Example:

```js
// 1. With safeguard
Array.prototype.doNotInclude = function (arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) arr = [arr];
  return this.filter((val, i) => {
    if (!arr.includes(i)) return val;
  });
};

console.log(['zero', 'one', 'two'].doNotInclude(0)); // executes normally

// 2. Without safeguard
Array.prototype.doNotInclude = function (arr) {
  //if (!Array.isArray(arr)) arr = [arr];
  return this.filter((val, i) => {
    if (!arr.includes(i)) return val;
  });
};

console.log(['zero', 'one', 'two'].doNotInclude(0)); // fails
```