# javascript array value as variable name , how I get them from function

Tags: javascript

I'm using array value as variable and then call the function N method, how I get them in function N.

I really want to simulate the Javascript array method, I don't want to use parameters to achieve it. For example,

```
 var p1 = [1,2,3,4,5];    p1.push(6);
```

```js
function _Array() {
      this._this = this;
    }
    _Array.prototype.show = function () {
        this._this.forEach(function(item){alert(item);})    //how to print 1,2,3,4,5
    };

    var p1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
    p1 = new _Array();

    //p1._Array.call(p1);        //not work 
  // new _Array().show.call(p1);   //not work 
   // p1.show();               //not work
```

Comment: say = function(items) {items.forEach(..)}; n = new N(); n.say(p2); ..? Question does not show a need to use call or apply here. Simply pass the array, using a parameter in the method. If there is a need to use call or apply, there should be a reason, such as the say function taking multiple params or such.

Comment: I really want to simulate Javascript array method, I don't want to user parameter 
to achieve it.

Comment: What is “simulate JavaScript array method”? This question is unclear, especially as there is such ‘method’. Do you want to “add a new method to the Array type?”, perhaps. That’s possible: however, _named parameters are still used/useful_. Too many different concerns being mixed up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57067019/2864740 - if it’s about “adding a new method to the Array type”, etc. Notice that parameters are used, as indicated by the first comment. It doesn’t matter if the function is added to N.proto or Array.proto.

Comment: The question is also very confusing with needless useless artifacts like “p1 = [1,2..]” which is _immediately_ followed by another assignment to p1 (so that _p1 no longer represents an array_). The usage of “_Array” to denote a type is not doing any favors either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store that in the instance

```js
function N(arr) {
  this._this = arr
}

N.prototype.say = function () {
  this._this.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item)
  })
}

p1 = new N([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
p1.say()
```

Comment: I really want to simulate Javascript array method, I don't want to user parameter 
to achieve it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are insistent on wanting to write a method that takes the array by reference, you can modify the array prototype like so:

```
Array.prototype.show = function() {
  this.forEach(item => alert(item));
}
```

However, it is a ***VERY BAD IDEA*** to modify the built in object prototypes, as this can cause conflicts with external libraries implementing their own "show" function that is being used differently, or cause incompatibilities with future versions of JS that implements this method.

It would be far more prudent in most situations to pass the array as a parameter, unless you have a very specific reason why you're not doing so. In that case, you should at least prefix the method with some sort of project identifier to minimize the chances of conflicts occurring.